# onSharedPreferenceChanged doesn't proc, Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have my settings activity set up with my < PreferenceScreen > for choosing the app settings.
What I want to do is have my changes do immediate effect, and not on app restart.
Naturally I wanted to use  OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener , but if I try to put a Log in onSharedPreferenceChanged, it never procs on changed selection. My plan was to recreate() on preference changed, so my preference apply function would proc on onCreate() with that recreate().
The problem is, as previously stated that onSharedPreferenceChanged never procs.

I tried registering the listener as it was stated somewhere, but it didn't help.

Can anyone help me?

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback,
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


val Tag = "My Activity:"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val prefMen = SharedPreferencesManager(this)
    prefMen.loadTheme()

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_preference, MainPreference()).commit()
    } else {
        title = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(TAG_TITLE)
    }

    supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
            setTitle("Settings")
        }
    }

    setUpToolbar()

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)

}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    outState.putCharSequence(TAG_TITLE, title)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    if (supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

private fun setUpToolbar() {
    supportActionBar?.setTitle("Settings")
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

}

class MainPreference : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }

}

override fun onPreferenceStartFragment(
    caller: PreferenceFragmentCompat?,
    pref: Preference?
): Boolean {
    val args = pref?.extras
    val fragment = pref?.fragment?.let {
        supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            classLoader,
            it
        ).apply {
            arguments = args
            setTargetFragment(caller, 0)
        }
    }
    fragment?.let {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_preference, it)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }

    title = pref?.title

    return true
}

companion object {
    private val TAG_TITLE = "PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY"
}

override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
    recreate()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two mistakes. The first is that you never register your listener. You have called `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in your `onStart()` instead of `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`.

Secondly, you are not listening to the same SharedPreferences as the settings Fragment is using. PreferenceFragmentCompat by default uses the default shared preferences of the whole application. But you are listening to preferences retrieved with `Activity.getPreferences()`, which are not the default preferences, but rather a SharedPreferences instance that is [named after the Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getPreferences(int)).

So you should switch to using default shared preferences, because the private shared preferences of the Activity will not be as easy to get a reference to in other activities.

I would also register in `onCreate()` instead of `onStart()` so you aren't registering multiple times. I don't know if that really matters, but the documentation doesn't specify what happens when you repeatedly register the same listener. Maybe it would fire the callback repeatedly, which could end up wasting your time hunting the bug later.

```
override fun onCreate() {
    // ...
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}
```

It is possible to specify the SharedPreferences that will be used by PreferenceFragmentCompat, but the default preferences are the easiest to use for settings that you want to access from across your application.